# Passing references in a recursive function

Tags: recursion, rust, lifetime

I want to implement a binary-search tree in Rust. When I tried to implement the `find` function, I met with a tricky situation.

You can open [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a18c36782c0f63d53dcf70a4eacbf31f) to look the whole code. You can use `Test` command to debug the situation.

The core function looks like this:

```rust
fn find(&self, value: T) -> Option<&Node<T>> {
    match value.cmp(&self.value) {
        std::cmp::Ordering::Equal => Some(self),
        std::cmp::Ordering::Greater => match &self.left {
            None => None,
            Some(node) => node.borrow().find(value),
        },
        std::cmp::Ordering::Less => match &self.right {
            None => None,
            Some(node) => node.borrow().find(value),
        },
    }
}
```

I tried to add a lifetime marker, but it failed to work properly:

```
fn find<'a>(&'a self, value: T) -> Option<&'a Node<T>> {
    match value.cmp(&self.value) {
        std::cmp::Ordering::Equal => Some(self),
        std::cmp::Ordering::Greater => match &self.left {
            None => None,
            Some(node) => node.borrow().find(value),
        },
        std::cmp::Ordering::Less => match &self.right {
            None => None,
            Some(node) => node.borrow().find(value),
        },
    }
}
```

Below are the complete code, the core function is in `impl<T: Ord + Debug> Node<T>`

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, fmt::Debug, rc::Rc};

struct Tree<T> {
    root: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    left: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
    right: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}

impl<T: Ord + Debug> Tree<T> {
    #[inline]
    fn new() -> Self {
        Tree { root: None }
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, value: T) {
        match self.root {
            None => self.root = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new(value)))),
            Some(ref mut node) => node.borrow_mut().insert(value),
        }
    }

    fn print(&self) {
        match self.root {
            None => println!("None"),
            Some(ref node) => node.borrow().print(),
        }
    }

    fn find(&self, value: T) -> Option<&Node<T>> {
        match self.root {
            None => None,
            Some(ref node) => node.borrow().find(value),
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Ord + Debug> Node<T> {
    #[inline]
    fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        Node {
            value,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        }
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, value: T) {
        match value.cmp(&self.value) {
            std::cmp::Ordering::Equal => {
                println!("Found {:?} already exists, omit the insertion", value);
            }
            std::cmp::Ordering::Greater => match self.left {
                None => self.left = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new(value)))),
                Some(ref mut node) => node.borrow_mut().insert(value),
            },
            std::cmp::Ordering::Less => match self.right {
                None => self.right = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new(value)))),
                Some(ref mut node) => node.borrow_mut().insert(value),
            },
        }
    }

    fn print(&self) {
        match self.left {
            None => println!("None"),
            Some(ref node) => node.borrow().print(),
        }
        println!("{:?}", self.value);
        match self.right {
            None => println!("None"),
            Some(ref node) => node.borrow().print(),
        }
    }
    fn find(&self, value: T) -> Option<&Node<T>> {
        match value.cmp(&self.value) {
            std::cmp::Ordering::Equal => Some(self),
            std::cmp::Ordering::Greater => match &self.left {
                None => None,
                Some(node) => node.borrow().find(value),
            },
            std::cmp::Ordering::Less => match &self.right {
                None => None,
                Some(node) => node.borrow().find(value),
            },
        }
    }
}

// unit tests
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_insert() {
        let mut tree = Tree::new();
        tree.insert(1);
        tree.insert(2);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_find() {
        let mut tree = Tree::new();
        tree.insert(1);
        tree.insert(2);
        tree.insert(3);
        tree.insert(1);
        tree.insert(2);
        println!("{:?}", tree.find(1).unwrap());
        tree.print()
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_print() {
        let mut tree = Tree::new();
        tree.insert(3);
        tree.insert(4);
        tree.insert(9);
        tree.insert(3);
        tree.insert(2);
        tree.insert(3);
        tree.print()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `Rc<RefCell>` for tree instead of `Box`?

Comment: As I find it easy to implement the `insert` function using `Rc<RefCell<>>` but I failed to implement that using `Box`.

Comment: TL;DR: This can't be fixed. This is the same problem as [here](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/fourth-iteration.html#iter), if I remember correctly.

Comment: Means that I can't pass reference in recursive function? 

Comment: [Here's how you implement it correctly, with `Box`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=41d55aa6807732599bd14872a87ebb8d). Much simpler too.

Comment: The problem is the return, not the argument. And is it's not a simple value but a `RefCell`. Yes, you can't return a reference to the contents of `RefCell`. Many times you can return a guard, but in this case you cannot do even that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I need to learn more to have a more comprehensive understanding of that